# What is delaying the rollout of the new top bar to other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, top-bar

In [this related question on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343268/is-the-new-top-bar-going-to-be-rolled-out-to-all-se-sites-in-the-future), we were advised that the new top bar navigation on Stack Overflow would be rolled out to all of the other Stack Exchange sites (fixing the annoyance that site switching moves from right > left).

But that was 6 months ago. Is there anything specific causing the delay? Just curious.

Comment: Well, for starters, the review queues are getting fuller, probably because people are less likely to click the [review icon in the new design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350836/4751173).

Comment: There's another way to restore consistency...

Comment: Check out [my new post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network) with an update on this very topic.

Comment: Thanks for the update Joe, looking forward to it!