# Why does Stack Overflow have a different top navigation than other sites?

Tags: discussion, design, top-bar

In the top navigation bar, why does SO have a different location for going to other SE sites (on the right side of navigation bar) but all other SE sites have that option on left side of navigation bar? The *Inbox* and *Reputation* buttons are also on a different side.

Why is it so? Why not a total uniform design like the other 169 **SE** sites?

Comment: Related [What is delaying the rollout of the new top bar to other Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299720/312043)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's a new design, which is rolled out on Stack Overflow (and Meta Stack Overflow, and the foreign language Stack Overflow sites) first. It needs to be tested for a while; e.g. one of the observations is that the [review queues are less active](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown?noredirect=1&lq=1) than they used to be.

From the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/14/why-stack-overflow-redesigned-the-top-navigation/):

> #### Next Steps
>
> There's a running list of ideas we'd like to try in the near future. We plan on iterating upon the design and functionality of our new top nav in a series of A/B tests. *There are also early-phase explorations into how this might roll out to international and other Stack Exchange community sites.*

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

So it's coming to other sites as well, but not just yet.

Comment: Additional note: on Stack Overflow we have new top nav indeed, but it's a hybrid of header (logo + nav) with something we call 'topbar' (inbox, achievements, search etc. which is that black bar on top of other sites). And we are *not* going to launch this kind of hybrid on other sites - instead we only gonna update topbar to be more in line with what we have on SO (in terms of layout, position of elements etc.)

Comment: @Paweł I'm not following you entirely. Do you have a preview you can share?

Comment: https://cl.ly/0b1H0x2r1z28

Answer (score 2):

The top navigation will be rolled to other sites too in the future. First it appeared on SO as an experimental update.

Not only SO but it is there for SO local versions